# Laravel google/apiclient Cannot handle token prior to [timestamp]

Tags: laravel-5, google-oauth

I'm trying to verify an idToken from google and I keep getting this error. I'm using angular as a font end and laravel as a backend and I just want to verify the idToken before I sign them in.

```
{message: "Cannot handle token prior to 2018-03-19T22:12:10+0000",…}
exception : "Firebase\JWT\BeforeValidException"
file : "/home/vagrant/web/scratk/office-api/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php"
line : 124
message : "Cannot handle token prior to 2018-03-19T22:12:10+0000"
trace : [{,…},…]
```

This is my function within Laravel:

```
public function socialSignIn(Request $request, Response $response) {
    JWT::$leeway = 5;

    $date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

    $provider = $request->input('provider');

    if ($provider == 'google') {

        $id_token = $request->header('Authorization');

        $id_token = str_replace("Bearer ","",$id_token);

        $CLIENT_ID = Config::get('google.client_id');

        $client = new \Google_Client();
        $client->setDeveloperKey($CLIENT_ID);
        $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
        if ($payload) {
            // $userid = $payload['sub'];
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
            // return response()->json([
            //     'failed'
            // ], 300);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of googling, I found out why I was getting this error and its because the system clock on my VM was behind. Because it was the 17th and the date on the VM was sat 3 march.

To double check, you can check the date with `date`

So the way of getting around this was opening the VM and the ssh and using these commands `sudo service ntp stop` then `sudo ntpd -gq` then after this has run through run `sudo service ntp start`.

After this, you can run `date` and it should pass out the actual date.